# ST datePicker and date issue

Tags: datepicker, sencha-touch

Platform is Sencha Touch 2.1.1. I am using a datPicker in a form panel as follows:

```
        {
            xtype: 'datepickerfield',
            destroyPickerOnHide: true,
            name : 'dateOfEvaluation', 
            label: 'Date of evaluation',
            dateFormat: 'm/d/Y',
            value: new Date(),
            picker: {
                yearFrom: 2013
            }
        },
```

which is being saved to as a date type in my model:

```
        {name: 'dateOfEvaluation', type: 'date'},
```

If there is a value in the store it gets rendered via an itemTpl via the follwing method:

```
onSelectSiteGeneral: function(view, index, target, record, event) {
    console.log('Selected a SiteGeneral from the list');
    var siteGeneralForm = Ext.Viewport.down('siteGeneralForm');

    if(!siteGeneralForm){
        siteGeneralForm = Ext.widget('siteGeneralForm');
    }    
    siteGeneralForm.setRecord(record);
    siteGeneralForm.showBy(target);
}
```

This all works fine and dandy.

The problem is with records that do not have dates saved in them. In localStorage for a date type, the null/empty value seems to be 0, which gets displayed on my above form as '12/31/1969.' I know I could write a handler to have this display as the current date, but am sure how to proceed (I cannot use a default value: new Date(), btw, since this does not work with a value already in the data store being rendered to the form). I know I would have to add n-days to zero to get the current date, but am unsure how to get this to rerender in my form.

Any suggestions for how to get the 0th date to show up as a more realistic date, such as the current date (I will stress that default dates do not seem to work when using the above method, onSelectSiteGeneral). Grazie!